# Shortcut for Guava's Optional use with exceptions?

Tags: java, guava

I keep writing specific exception throwers in the case the Optional is absent.

For instance:

```
Optional<?> optional = ...;
if (!optional.isPresent()) {
  throw new MyException();
}
Object result = optional.get();
```

I find this code not very fluent, especially the use of the bang (!). I'd rather like writing something like:

```
Optional<?> optional = ...;
Object result = optional.orThrow(MyException.class);
```

Is there such a shortcut in Guava that I haven't found yet?

Comment: General question. If the thing you are checking is Optional, isn't it against the concept of "optional" to have a method like "Optional.orThrow"?

Comment: Totally agree. If `isAbsent` (added in release 11) is a valid condition, it should not result in an exception. The point of `Optional` is that absent is a valid not exceptional case. If absent is an exceptional case, your method should just return the object and throw and exception in the absent case.

Comment: @black panda: then why can I give a default value with the `or()` method? It's a kind of allowing a default behavior to happen, why not another?
@ John B: One of the use case is a rather generic XML attribute extractor: that attribute may or may not be present, so the method returns an `Optional`. Then the caller may want to enforce the presence of the value (by throwing an exception), or get the value if any, or even retrieve a default value. The extractor method just doesn't know what the caller wants to do with the value, so it must return a `Optional`. Why would this use case be invalid?

Comment: Plus, you are answering with the only thing I strongly disagree with Guava: the "use exactly as we intend in our limited set of use-cases or just leave" approach. This approach is the only downside I see in Guava - a big one, but still, the only one. I love all the rest. I would have hoped not to find the same "no"-wall over here. By the way, release 11 doesn't include `isAbsent()` (see issue 734 of Guava)

Comment: @ogregoire: it is common and expected behavior that if something is optional then a default value is acceptable. That's a natural extension of something being optional. "You don't specify it? Oh well, it's optional anyway, I'll use the default value." Not "This is optional. You didn't provide it? Then I'll throw an exception because it's mandatory that it be there."

Comment: Of course anyone can design their software the way they want. It's ok to believe otherwise. It's merely my opinion that optional means that it's not mandatory. Otherwise, it's...mandatory. This seems like a good  and understandable design on the part of the Guava developers (I don't know their true intentions, since I am not a Guava developer.)

Comment: Short: if I develop an API, I'm glad that people find other ways to use it, ways I didn't intend originally. I'm not going to debate further on Guava's team approach. Regarding the matter itself, it looks like you think only about the use-case of passing an `Optional` as an argument to method (tell me if I'm wrong). I think that an `Optional` may be returned by a method that doesn't guarantee to provide an actual answer. This case is interesting as well, but seems discarded. It can even be documented: "if a method accepts an `Optional`, it's wrong to use `orThrow()`".

Comment: I don't understand. You can still use the API and throw your own exception. They are not preventing you from adding the throw to your own code. But it's still their API, and if they don't want to put the kitchen sink and the washer in to satisfy every whim, that's understandable. They like it to be clean, efficient to their liking. They often welcome and analyze suggestions from other people in quite an open manner. Let me stop...it's sounding like I'm defending a bunch of people I don't even know :)

Comment: Of course, we can use our own code to do this behavior. We're in no way stucked. Of course, it's Google's API. I don't understand your point here either. :)

Comment: My point is that the library is not taking a "use exactly as we intend...or just leave" kind of approach  They are clearly providing an extensible approach to the library, considering ideas from the public on an almost daily basis, and allowing you from easily using the library to reach your goal, even though they don't put every single thing in it imaginable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is worth nothing that Java 8's `Optional` has an `orElseThrow(Supplier)` method that allows the requested behavior.

It is used like this:

```
Optional<Object> reference = Optional.empty()
reference.orElseThrow(MyOwnException::new); // Throws a new MyOwnException
```

Furthermore, a method in Java 10 was added, `orElseThrow()`, which throws a `NoSuchElementException` if no value is present.

```
Optional<Object> reference = Optional.empty();
reference.orElseThrow(); // Throws a new NoSuchElementException
```

Answer (score 21):

Speaking as a Guava developer, let me try to unpack the logic here.  Responding both to the original question, and the comment thread directly on the question:

It is absolutely the case that we try to force Guava users to respect our standards of good programming habits.  (Our standards are *strongly* influenced by e.g. Effective Java.)

That said, I agree that there are perfectly good use cases for the behavior you're referring to in this particular question: "if absent, throw an exception."  Perhaps you're implementing a class that can be accessed both ways -- one method with an Optional return value, and one method   that assumes that the value will always be present, throwing an exception otherwise.  The Deque interface, for instance, provides special-valued and exception-throwing versions of peek, poll, and offer.

All that said, to the best of my understanding, the True Guava Way to do this is...

```
if (value.isPresent()) {
  return value.get();
} else {
  throw new MyException();
}
```

The "orThrow" method you propose requires reflection (!!), doesn't let you customize the exception with a useful message, etc.  The "normal way" is perfectly readable and more efficient.

Sometimes Guava doesn't provide explicit support for things because for those use cases, we think it's best done just the "normal way."  I think this is the case here.

Comment: Well, an `orThrow()` method doesn't specially require reflection: one can think about delegating the instanciation of the `Exception` to a `Supplier` or a `Function`. Anyways, the main point is that the "True Guava Way to do this" is repeated roughly 50 times with roughly 10 different exceptions, and only with new code produced since Guava 10! We don't want to duplicate that kind of code again and again. We've created several a helper methods (1 per `Exception` constructor + extras) and that's enough for us. I just wanted to know if an alternative existed, which doesn't. I won't open a ticket.

Comment: A Supplier or Function would require the use of icky anonymous classes, and still more code than is required in the straightforward approach.  If you have that much repetition it might be appropriate, although I'd think that the most effective helper methods would be one helper for each exception type, which seems to be what you've done.

Comment: Given that Java's `Optional` has been around for a while and that Guava recommends using Java's `Optional` whenever possible, I removed the check from your answer to put it to mine which speaks about Java's `Optional` capabilities. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way to do it without additions to Guava:

```
Object result = optional.or(new Supplier() {
    public Object get() {
        throw new MyException();
    }
});
```

MyException has to be unchecked, but this does allow you to pass arguments to its constructor.  And of course if you're doing it a lot you can store the Supplier somewhere and use it each place you need it.

```
Object result = optional.or(SomethingIsMissing.INSTANCE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would belong to the library. I find it very rare to find a library that receives an instance of an exception to be throw in case something doesn't go as expected, especially because in many cases an exception must have a message indicating what went wrong.

That being said, you can create your own Optional class that does what you need. Or you can create your own OptionalHelper class where you have a method that does what you want:

```
public class OptionalHelper {
   public <T> T valueOrThrow(final Optional<T> optional) throws MyException {
      if (optional.isPresent()) {
          return optional.get();
      } else {
          throw new MyException();
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT:

Supposing you have a custom class that receives a parameter/ field name that you need to check, you could have a better approach similar to what Preconditions does:

```
public class OptionalHelper {
   public <T> T valueOrFail(final Optional<T> optional, final String fieldName) throws OptionalNotPresentError {
      if (optional.isPresent()) {
          return optional.get();
      } else {
          throw new OptionalNotPresentError(fieldName);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you pass your own exception class, you will have to instantiate it with Class.newInstance() before throwing it.

Comment: How would you declare this .newInstance'd exception in the throws clause? You'd have to have an general Exception subclass that you know about that contains the Exception you want to throw, right? It feels messy to me.

Comment: It is a messy approach for sure. This is why they don't have it in the library and this is why I didn't include it in my example (only added it as a comment). Answering your question, you could get away with declaring it if you extend your exception class from RuntimeException (and not from Exception).

Comment: It would be better to have a pre-defined exception class and pass a message/ enum value/ something else correlated with the situation being checked, and then throw that exception if the wanted object is absent from the Optional class.

Comment: +1 for being an option for implementing the OP, even though the OP shouldn't be implemented. More generalization of the solution would be nice.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't asking for an implementation. I do already have one, that is meant to be "while Guava doesn't implement it". My question is really about: "does Guava have such a method or not"? The most appropriate answer is no, unless there actually is and I just can't find it.

Comment: @ogregoire I don't think it has and I don't think such method belongs in the API.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (no reflection, just type inference):

```
public class ExceptionSupplier<T, E extends RuntimeException> implements Supplier<T> {

    private final E exception;

    private ExceptionSupplier(E exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public static <T, E extends RuntimeException> ExceptionSupplier<T, E> throwA(E exception) {
        return new ExceptionSupplier<T, E>(exception);
    }    

    public static <T, E extends RuntimeException> ExceptionSupplier<T, E> throwA(@SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters") Class<T> class_, E exception) {
        return new ExceptionSupplier<T, E>(exception);
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Something something = optionalSomething.or(throwA(Something.class, new SomeException()));
```

This probably can be extended even further, but for my use cases it's sufficient and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

See [official issue here](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1121)

> Decision: NO - too expensive, not a common pattern, can just use !isPresent(), throw

Since `optional.orThrow(new Exception())` is not good for performance, I prefer **static import**, which is similar with[@timk 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540914/2218838).

```
Result result = optional.or(throwException());
```

Equal to

```
Result result = optional.or(SomeSupplier.throwException());
```

Static method

```
public static Supplier<Result> throwException() {
    return new Supplier<Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result get() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    };
}
```

===========

The stack trace looks like

```
Exception ... RuntimeException
at SomeSupplier$1.get(SomeSupplier.java:line where throw RuntimeException)
at SomeSupplier$1.get(SomeSupplier.java:1)
at com.google.common.base.Absent.or(Absent.java:60)
at line where call optional.or(throwException());
```

Comment: What does the stack trace of this look like? How does it go in tracking down an issue when you see this in a log?

Comment: @Ray I think it is a pattern that throw a specific exception then somewhere will handle it. Further more, the log can be understood.

Comment: Thanks for adding. Wasn't sure how the anonymous class gets involved in the stack trace, and I think it's relevant to the discussion

Comment: @Ray My pleasure. Note "$1" in "SomeSupplier$1", that's the anonymous class defined in SomeSupplier.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's an elegant of doing this in Guava:

```
Optional<?> optional = ...;
Object result = optional.or(supplyError(MyException::new));
```

Using the following helper method:

```
public static Supplier supplyError(Supplier<Error> errorSupplier) {
    return () -> { throw errorSupplier.get(); };
}
```