# Giving a custom message on absence in a Guava Optional.get()

Tags: java, guava

I have a method which returns an `Optional`. I'd like to customise the exception thrown if the caller does a `get()` when the optional value is absent, to include some context information. Currently `Absent.get()` will simply `throw new IllegalStateException("value is absent");` (and it's locked down very neatly!).

Is there a suggested best practice here?

What I imagine is something like an `Optional.absentThrowing(String message)` which returns an `Absent` with a custom message in the exception -- and possibly variants taking `Supplier<? extends String>` and/or `Supplier<? extends IllegalStateException>`.  This would allow code such as:

```
if (kitchen.isOpen()) {
    if (soupQ.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.absentThrowing("out of soup");
    }
    return Optional.of(soupQ.remove());
}
return Optional.absentThrowing("kitchen closed");
```

This could also be used caller-side giving a solution to [Shortcut for Guava's Optional use with exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534442/shortcut-for-guavas-optional-use-with-exceptions) which doesn't have the reflection or complexity objections raised at that post:

```
optional.or(Optional.absentThrowing("no soup for you")).get()
```

Good idea? Bad idea?  Simply not worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Why should we have Optional.absentThrowing("out of soup");

Can't we just throw corresponding exception? Smth. like that:

```
if (kitchen.isOpen()) {
   if (soupQ.isEmpty()) {
    return throw new IllegalStateException("out of soup");
   }
return Optional.of(soupQ.remove());
}
return throw IllegalStateException("kitchen closed");
```

I think it's better to throw a specific exception as it will be more intuitive what was wrong. And IllegalStateException isn't appropriate for all cases.

Comment: I don't want the method which returns `Optional` to throw an error immediately.  It should only throw if the caller attempts to access the contents of an empty `Optional`.  That is, the caller can decide whether in a given case the `Optional` is permitted to be absent.